# I can't detect markers with my iphone or laptop and screencapture creates a black jpeg

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

Have no clue what happens. It looks like the camera is not helping. What do you think?

[Goodprint Media AR](https://goodprint.site/AR/happyholidayscoldiron.html)

I've tried different ways of markers including the default which is the one I left here for you to test, but for me, nothing works. Am I missing something? I just want the tree to stay quiet over the QR or marker or whatever.

Also, screen capture is not working. Here is the code for you wise people who can enlight me!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>"Happy Holidays ColdIron"</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
   <style>
        #screenshotButton {
            position: fixed;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="screenshotButton">Take Screenshot</button> <!-- Screenshot Button -->

    <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;'>
        <!-- AR content will be added here -->
        <a-entity position="0 0 -5" rotation="0 0 0">
            
            <a-entity gltf-model="http://goodprint.site/AR/cuban_christmass.glb" 
                  position="0 -0.5 -8" 
                  scale="0.05 0.05 0.05" 
                  rotation="0 0 0" 
                  width="3" 
                  height="3" 
                  color="#7BC8A4"
                  animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; dur: 10000; easing: linear">
            </a-entity>
          
            <a-text value="Japi jolideis\nKati Coldiron"   
                position="0 2.1 -8" 
                width="4" 
                color="white"
                side="double"
                animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; dur: 10000; easing: linear">
            </a-text>

            <a-text value="CUBA \nIS NOT \nFREE" 
                align="center"
                position="0 0.5 -8" 
                scale="2 2 2" 
                width="4" 
                color="red"
                animation__fade="property: opacity; from: 1; to: 0.05; dir: alternate; dur: 4000; loop: true">
            </a-text>
        </a-entity>
          <a-marker preset="hiro">
    
        <a-plane ></a-plane>
        <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>


</a-marker>

    </a-scene>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('screenshotButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var canvas = document.querySelector('a-scene').canvas;
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                var pageTitle = document.title.replace(/"/g, '');
                link.download = pageTitle + '.jpg';
                link.href = imgData.replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');
                link.click();
            }, 1000); // 500ms delay to ensure the scene is rendered
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: I suggest you to check [screenshot component](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/screenshot.md) from a-frame docs.